# How can i prevent the super use privileges message from showing

Tags: flutter, terminal

I'm running flutter on Linux as root and each time i run a flutter command it shows the super user warning message every time i know it shows for other commands as well not just flutter commands so i don't want to show only for flutter commands other it is ok, any help!

Comment: Are your talking about the __"To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>". See "man sudo_root" for details."__ message ?

Comment: no this one   Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
   We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.

Comment: Where did you install flutter ? (in which folder)

Comment: in the Root folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is throwned by the [flutter command](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9248fda41005ce0af2e522fabd0e9fedf2b3c863/bin/internal/shared.sh#L181) itself upon detection of root and cannot be disabled by any means.

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354351/why-is-flutter-only-running-as-superuser) you have to install flutter in your user folder to get rid of the "annoying" message (but then, you won't be root).

Comment: thanks but i already know that, i'm just looking for a way to disable it for root, i don't want to switch to another user

Comment: The message is throwned by the flutter tool itself. There's no way to disable it

Comment: oh really, are you sure ?

Comment: Yep. [Line 154](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/bin/flutter) of the flutter command

Comment: Flutter is installed in my user dir and is owned by the local user but this warning persists.

Answer (score 2):

Flutter just says running flutter as the root user is not a good idea. As, all its future plugin installations etc might be needing root privileges.
So, give your current user the permission to r/w the flutter folder. The warning will disappear.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /the/exact/path/of/your/flutter/repo/
```

This worked for me.